# Learning Objective-C. Using Xcode 3.2.1. What is error: Program received signal: “EXC_ARITHMETIC”

Tags: objective-c, xcode, programming-languages

I am learning Objective-C using Stephen Kochan's excellent book "Programming in Objective-C 2.0". I am new also to Xcode. So far all my exercises have worked fine, but when I run program 7.6 FractionTest on page 153 I get the console message "Program received signal: "EXC_ARITHMETIC". The status shows that the program succeeded, but I don't see any output. Can anybody suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that if the denominator is zero (i.e. a divide-by-zero error).

---

[EXC_ARITHMETIC (SIGFPE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGFPE) is signaled when the CPU detects an invalid calculation. Some causes include divide by zero, integer overflow, etc., and integer divide by zero is most likely the reason since you're implementing a Fraction class.

Comment: Dear KennyTM

Once again, thanks for your help. I hadn't seen that I had left an important line out of my code, resulting ultimately in a divide by zero error. The program works well now.

Kind Regards

Derry

Comment: Note that you pretty much *can't do anything at all* in a signal handler.   They are not designed to be a mechanism for catching errors and recovering to continue execution.

Answer (score 0):

EXC_ARITHMETIC is an exception in some sort of floating point operation. I don't have a copy of *Programming in Objective-C 2.0*, so I can't look up the problem. A code listing might be helpful.

If I had to take a stab in the dark, though, I'd say it might be a division-by-zero error.

Comment: Dear mipadi

Once again, thanks for your help. I hadn't seen that I had left an important line out of my code, resulting ultimately in a divide by zero error. The program works well now.

Kind Regards

Derry