# how to catch exc_arithmetic in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to catch a divide by 0 arithmetic exception in my code but it looks like NSException is not catching that and program is terminating with message `exc_arthimetic` error. What is the way to catch the exception

```
     @try {

         int k;

         printf("please enter k value \n");
         scanf("%i",&k);

         int j=1;

         // testing division 1/0 condition
         int i=j/k;
         NSLog(@" value of i= %i",i);
     }

     @catch (NSException *exception) {
         NSLog(@"exception is = %@  reason is %@",[exception name],[exception reason]);
     }
     @finally {
         NSLog(@"inside finally");
     }


     NSLog(@" last line");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I catch global exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826351/how-do-i-catch-global-exceptions)

Comment: i know but since i didn't find any solution for handling this error, i raised this :)

Comment: You raised the question using a technique that you know doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exc_arthimetic is not an exception but rather a signal sent by the OS.  I would suggest checking that the denominator is not zero before trying to divide.

In order to catch this signal is more complicated and likely not worth the effort.

Take a look at 
[Learning Objective-C. Using Xcode 3.2.1. What is error: Program received signal: “EXC_ARITHMETIC”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708850/learning-objective-c-using-xcode-3-2-1-what-is-error-program-received-signal)

Comment: "more complicated" is a huge understatement;  you pretty much *can't do anything at all* in a signal handler.   They are not designed to be a mechanism for catching errors and recovering to continue execution.   You should prevent the exception from happening in the first place.